# Counting number of SELECTED rows in Oracle with PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, select

I'm doing this project for university, which is basically a movie database and for a couple of queries I need to know how many rows were selected. For now, there's 2 situations where I need this:

- Display a **single movie** information. I want the count of selected rows to know if the database contains the selected movie by the user. *Or is there a better solution for this?*
- That selected movie has genres, I need to know how many so that I can construct a string with the genres separated by `|` without adding one to the end of the string.

With MySQL this is easy, I just query the database and use `mysql_num_rows()` but `oci_num_rows()` doesn't work quite the same for the SELECT statement.

The only solution I found with OCI/PHP is this:

```
if(is_numeric($mid) && $mid > 0) {
        $stid = oci_parse($db,
            'SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM_ROWS
            FROM movies
            WHERE mid = '.$mid
        );

        oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NUM_ROWS', $num_rows);
        oci_execute($stid);
        oci_fetch($stid);

        if($num_rows > 0) {
            $stid = oci_parse($db,
                'SELECT title, year, synopsis, poster_url
                FROM movies
                WHERE mid = '.$mid
            );

            oci_execute($stid);

            $info = oci_fetch_assoc($stid);

            $stid = oci_parse($db,
                'SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM_ROWS
                FROM genres g, movies_genres mg
                WHERE mg.mid = '.$mid.' AND g.gid = mg.gid'
            );

            oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NUM_ROWS', $num_rows);
            oci_execute($stid);
            oci_fetch($stid);

            $stid = oci_parse($db,
                'SELECT g.name AS genre
                FROM genres g, movies_genres mg
                WHERE mg.mid = '.$mid.' AND g.gid = mg.gid');

            oci_execute($stid);

            $genres_list = null;

            while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
                $genres_list .= $row['GENRE'];

                if($num_rows > 1) {
                    $genres_list .= ' | ';
                    $num_rows--;
                }
            }

            $Template->assignReferences(array(
                'Index:LinkURI'    => $link_uri,
                'Movie:Title'      => $info['TITLE'],
                'Movie:Year'       => $info['YEAR'],
                'Movie:GenresList' => $genres_list,
                'Movie:Synopsis'   => $info['SYNOPSIS'],
                'Movie:PosterURL'  => $info['POSTER_URL'] // FIX: Handle empty poster link
            ));

            $Template->renderTemplate('movieinfo');
        } else {
            // TODO: How to handle this error?
        }
    } else {
        // TODO: How to handle this error?
    }
```

But I don't like it. I always need to make 2 queries to count the rows and then select the actual data and there's too many lines of code just to count the rows.

This code doesn't show it (haven't done it yet cause I'm looking for a better solution) but I'll also need to do the same for the movie directors/writers.

Is there any better and **simpler** solution to accomplish this or this is the only way?

I could add separators in the fetch loop until it finishes and then use PHP functions to trim the last separator from the string, but for this project I'm forced to use SEQUENCES, VIEWS, FUNCTIONS, PROCEDURES and TRIGGERS. Do any of these help solving my problem?

I know what SEQUENCES are, I'm using them already but I don't see how can they help.

For VIEWS, they probably wouldn't simplify the code that much (*it's basically a stored query right?*). For FUNCTIONS, PROCEDURES and TRIGGERS, as far as I understand them, I can't see how can they be of any help either.

Solutions?

Comment: Is your db schema set or should you create it?

Comment: how is oci_num_rows diffrent?

Comment: @Knubo Not sure what you are asking...

Comment: @Breezer With `mysql_num_rows()` I get the actual row count after doing a `mysql_query("SELECT....")`, the same is not true with `oci_num_rows()`.

Comment: Hi Can someone help me to fix following issue?..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755957/how-to-get-number-of-rows-in-php-oci-for-select-statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do the initial count at all? Just issue your select for the movie title. If it's not found, do your error processing. If it is, continue on! If you *really* need the count, use an analytic to add the count to your query:

```
'SELECT title, year, synopsis, poster_url
      , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY mid) mcount
   FROM movies
  WHERE mid = '.$mid
```

The same goes for your genre selection.

EDIT:

Oracle documentation on [Analytic Functions link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407). I found that analytics are a bit difficult to get from the Oracle docs. [Analytic functions by Example by Shouvik Basu](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55) provides some simple guidance as to how to use them and helped me quite a bit.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, I thought the result of `oci_fetch_assoc()` (or similar functions) would always return something true but I just realized they return false if nothing was selected, thanks. As for the count, just tested that and it seems to work fine but I don't understand it, where can I read more about it? (I can never find proper manual for Oracle SQL statements).

Comment: Edited my answer to provide a couple of links for analytics.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
$conn = oci_pconnect('user', 'password', 'connectionstring');
$resource = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($resource, OCI_DEFAULT);

$results=array();
$numrows = oci_fetch_all($resource, $results, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
```

Cheers

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: Please explain that oci_fetch_all() returns the count. And the result is in the 2nd parameter. So by this no need to do loop.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [ocirowcount](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ocirowcount.php) it should behave just like mysql_num_rows when making a select

Comment: How safe is that? I mean, the PHP manual states that ocirowcount is an alias for oci_num_rows but behaves differently. What are the chances of that behavior being "fixed" in the future?

Comment: you should use DCookies answer it's better

Comment: This alias has been deprecated, use oci_num_rows() instead

Answer (score -1):

oci_num_rows() Will give you the total row count if executed AFTER oci_fetch_array()

Comment: This function does not return number of rows selected! For SELECT statements this function will return the number of rows, that were fetched to the buffer with oci_fetch*() functions.