# How to get number of rows in php oci for SELECT statement

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I require help to get number of rows from select statement which contain where clause. I have tried various option. But it didn't work for me. I have shown my code snippet below.

I'm getting o/p "0 rows fetched". But when I executed select query on Oracle DB, then it returns 1 row.

Hence, please help me to get number of select statement in PHP through OCI.

Environment:

- Windows, Php 7.3 and Oracle 12c

Here is the Oracle query

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    no            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id            VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    fullname      VARCHAR2(200),
    email         VARCHAR2(200),
    givenname     VARCHAR2(200),
    first_login   VARCHAR2(200),
    last_login    VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO USERS (no, id,fullname,email,givenname,first_login,last_login) 
VALUES (1,'Bharat','Bharat','Bharat@gmail.com','Bharat','2019-08-20 03:08:42','2019-08-20 03:08:42');

INSERT INTO USERS (no, id,fullname,email,givenname,first_login,last_login) 
VALUES (1,'bharat','bharat','bharat@gmail.com','bharat','2019-08-20 03:08:42','2019-08-20 03:08:42');
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    # connect localhost oracle
    $conn = oci_connect('c##admin', 'ibm123', '127.0.0.1/XE');
    $res="array"; #array to staore oci_fetch_all o/p
    #thow error if unable to make connection
    if (!$conn) {
        $m = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($m['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    # Parse oracle query
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "select * from users where ID='Bharat'");
    # execute statement
    oci_execute($stid);
    # fetch all content
    $nrows = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);
    echo "$nrows rows fetched<br>\n";
    # Dump content
    var_dump($res);
    $numrows = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH);
    echo oci_num_rows($stid) . " rows.<br />\n";
    print_r($numrows);
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the output. Expected output is 1 row fetched.

```
0 rows fetched
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Are you sure that you have such a single matching record in your table, and have you tried executing this query directly against Oracle?

Comment: yes. here is oracle table.  <br/>
`CREATE TABLE users (
    no            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id            VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    fullname      VARCHAR2(200),
    email         VARCHAR2(200),
    givenname     VARCHAR2(200),
    first_login   VARCHAR2(200),
    last_login    VARCHAR2(200)
);`  <br/>

INSERT INTO USERS (id,fullname,email,givenname,first_login,last_login) 
VALUES ('bharat','bharat','bharat@gmail.com','bharat','2019-08-20 03:08:42','2019-08-20 03:08:42')   <br/>

Comment: In the INSERT you have as id: 'bharat' and 'Bharat' on your code, it's case sensitive, son be careful.

Comment: You are trying to search `'Bharat'` but your table has `'bharat'` value with small case `b`

Comment: I have tried Capital B also. it didn't work..

Comment: Here is updated query`CREATE TABLE users (
    no            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id            VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    fullname      VARCHAR2(200),
    email         VARCHAR2(200),
    givenname     VARCHAR2(200),
    first_login   VARCHAR2(200),
    last_login    VARCHAR2(200)
);` here is insert query.. `INSERT INTO USERS (no, id,fullname,email,givenname,first_login,last_login) 
VALUES (1,'Bharat','Bharat','Bharat@gmail.com','Bharat','2019-08-20 03:08:42','2019-08-20 03:08:42');`

Comment: I kept data in table with both small letter and capital letter.. Still it's not work for me.. here is o/p `1 bharat bharat bharat@gmail.com bharat 2019-08-20 03:08:42 2019-08-20 03:08:42
2 Bharat Bharat Bharat@gmail.com Bharat 2019-08-20 03:08:42 2019-08-20 03:08:42`

Comment: Can someone try on your local setup?.. I have given all details..

Comment: Try the query without the WHERE clause, just to check if the problem comes from the filter.

Comment: without where clause, it's show row count is 1 without where clause. But table contain around 5 entries. Even, I execute select * from USERS on oracle table. It show o/p 5. But php show row count 1.

Comment: it's show row count is 1 without where clause. But table contain around 5 entries. Even, I execute select * from USERS on oracle table. It show o/p 5. But php show row count 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function: oci_fetch_all($stid, $out) before using oci_num_rows($stid).